# Is the preposition “from” optional for “resign”?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, usage

I have visited [Google Ngram for “resign from” and “resign”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=resign%2C+resign+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresign%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresign%20from%3B%2Cc0). I found out that the use of “resign” alone is more common than “resign from”.

Does this mean that the preposition *from* becomes more optional?
If it doesn't, which of these two sentences is more correct using the verb *resign*?

1. I resigned from the position as worker of Fishy Company.
2. I resigned the position as worker of Fishy Company.

Comment: Doesn't your search for "resign" by itself also include every single example of "resign from"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In American English, it depends on context. When speaking of a job or title, 'from' is optional. The following are equivalent:

- I resigned from my senate seat.
- I resigned my senate seat.

But when the thing being resigned from is a collective body, 'from' is required.

- I resigned from the legislature.
- I resigned from Fishy Corporation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **resign** can take a direct object

**He resigned his post.**

or a preposition-phrase complement

**He resigned from his position.**

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally it is to resign from a post. Occasionally a prepositon after a verb can be dropped in the course of time. But Google Ngrams shows to resign from is the preferred construction.

[Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Resign%20from%2Cresign%20something&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CResign%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresign%20something%3B%2Cc0)